# Is it possible to get writing access to raw devices using python with windows?

Tags: python, windows, file-io

This is sort of a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522644/how-to-open-disks-in-windows-and-read-data-at-low-level). I want to know if you can access raw devices (i.e. `\\.\PhysicalDriveN`) in writing mode and if this should be the case, how.

Using Linux, write access can simply be achieved by using e.g. `open("/dev/sdd", "w+")` (provided that the script is running with root permissions). I assume that Mac OS behaves similar (with `/dev/diskN` as input file).

When trying the same command under Windows (with the corresponding path), it fails with the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+') or filename: '\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive3'
```

However, when trying to **read** from the PhysicalDrive, it *does work* (even the correct data is read). The shell is running with administrator permissions under Windows 7.

Is there any other way to accomplish this task using python while still keeping the script as platform-independent as possible?

### Edit:

I looked a bit further into what methods python provides for file handling and stumbled across [os.open](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.open). Opening the PhysicalDrive using `os.open(drive_string, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_BINARY)` returns no error. So far, so good. Now I have either the choice to write directly to this file-descriptor using [os.write](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.write), or use [os.fdopen](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fdopen) to get a file-object and write to it in the regular way.
Sadly, none of these possibilities works. In the first case (`os.write()`), I get this:

```
>>> os.write(os.open("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive3", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_BINARY), "test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

In the second case, I **can** create a file object with write permissions, but the writing itself fails (well, after enforcing its execution using `.flush()`):

```
>>> g = os.fdopen(os.open("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive3", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_BINARY), "wb")
>>> g.write("test")
>>> g.flush()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Did you try writing to it in `rb+` or `wb` or `ab+` or even just `rb` (I read it needs to be binary mode to work correctly on Windows)?

Comment: hmm. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027 makes it sound like you need write access to even read from the drive, so I don't think it can be a permission problem. This might be a question for [python-list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list). I'd like to know the answer myself.

Comment: @agf Yes, I did also try wb and w+b, but it doesn't work either. However, as mentioned before, reading (i.e. rb) *does* work! The question is mainly about the writing mode.

Comment: AH! Thank you very much. I didn't know that you can actually write in the `rb+` mode (I mean, `r` stands for **r**eading, doesn't it?). Well, I have tried it now and it does work without an error. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the great info in this question! I am able to open raw access to an SD card using the mode "rb+" as suggested, but I am unable to write - I get "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor". I've made sure I'm writing in multiples of 512. It appears I can successfully read data from the device. I am running Windows 7. Any other info from those of you who've got this to working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) and [agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf) pointed out in the comments (but I didn't really get it at first), the solution is rather simple: you have to open the device in the `rb+` mode, which opens the device for [updating](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) (as I have found out now..) without trying to replace it with a new file (which wouldn't work because the file is in fact a physical drive).

When writing, you have to write always a whole sector at a time (i.e. multiples of 512-byte), otherwise it fails.

In addition, the `.seek()` command can also jump only sector-wise. If you try to seek a position inside a sector (e.g. position `621`), the file object will jump to the beginning of the sector where your requested position is (i.e. to the beginning of the second sector, byte `512`).

Answer (score -1):

> Possibly in Win 7 you have to do something more extreme, such as locking the volume(s) for the disk beforehand with DeviceIoControl(hVol, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, ...)

In Win 7 you don't have to do that; opening and writing with 'rb+' mode works fine.