# Unable to open physical device using Python on Windows 7

Tags: python

I am trying to open the physical disk on a Windows 7 system using python 2.7 running under a shell with local admin privileges. I've tried all the suggestions in this article [Is it possible to get writing access to raw devices using python with windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135398/is-it-possible-to-get-writing-access-to-raw-devices-using-python-with-windows) and in the one it cites, to no avail. Using the exact same shell on the same system, I can open the device using PowerShell.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if __name__=="__main__":

    file = open('\\\\.\\C:', 'r')

    raw_record = file.read(1024)
```

The error I get is:

> Z:\devel\readraw>python readraw.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "readraw.py", line 9, in 
>       file = open('\\.\C:', 'r')    #code
>   IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\.\C:'

I also tried using os.open, and various variants on r, rb, and rb+ to no avail.

Thank you for your assistance with this.

Comment: Did you try disabling UAC and running the script?

Comment: Turning off UAC allows the script to run without error. But, a PowerShell script can open and read the device with UAC enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't running the shell with admin privileges.

Start a new cmd window as administrator or from the run search use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to open 'cmd' as administrator.

You can usually tell its an administrator shell beause the prompt says

`C:\Windows\system32`

The script will succeed when you are using an administrator shell.

tested using your exact code using the command:

`python scriptname.py`

in an administrator command shell.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and I was clearly sleep deprived. Thank you for taking the time to kindly point out the error of my ways.