# Get hex-values / raw data from $MFT on NTFS Filesystem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before you say "There´s already a thread covering that" - read further, there´s not.

I simply need to "address" the very first sector of a NTFS-Filesystem and read byte after byte (raw data). I do NOT need a program which does this, I need the code.

What I got so far:

```
drive = r"\\.\PhysicalDrive1"
pyLog = "C:\\ohMyPy\mft.txt"

hd = open(drive,encoding='cp850')
mft = hd.readlines(1024*10000)

with open(pyLog,'w',encoding='cp850') as f:
    f.writelines(mft)
    f.close
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135398/is-it-possible-to-get-writing-access-to-raw-devices-using-python-with-windows

Comment: unrelated: the purpose of `with`-statement here is to close the file even if an exception occurs -- remove `f.close()` (completely unrelated: to call a function in Python, you need to add parentheses: `f.close` -> `f.close()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the files in binary mode (`'rb'`/`'wb'`) otherwise Python will modify newline characters on Windows. Encoding is not needed when the file is opened in binary mode. Also, you can open both files in the same context manager (`with`) as shown below.

```
drive_filename = r'\\.\PhysicalDrive1'
log_filename = r'C:\ohMyPy\mft.txt'

with open(drive_filename, 'rb') as drive, open(log_filename, 'wb') as logfile:
    logfile.write(drive.read(1024*10000))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can read my MBR as follows;

```
drive = r"\\.\PhysicalDrive0"
hd = open(drive,'rb')
mbr = hd.read(512)
```

magic is in 'rb' = open file for reading in binary mode, i.e. do not change line-end characters.

Comment: note: on Python 3 (see the question tag): binary mode (`'rb'`) is more than *"do not change line-end characters"* -- it means that `.read()` method returns `bytes` object while it returns a Unicode string `str` in text mode (`'r'`). There are other differences (the file objects are represented by different classes).