# Writing raw data to physical disk (flash drive) fails with "Bad file descriptor" on windows - Python

Tags: python, windows, file-io, io

I am trying to perform direct data reading and writing to a USB flash drive as a physical drive on windows (10 if it matters). I am using Python to do that.

I have followed the following discussion:

[get writing access to raw devices using python with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135398/is-it-possible-to-get-writing-access-to-raw-devices-using-python-with-windows)

I ran into the same problem [kcstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855030/kcstrom) had in that question. I get a

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\script.py", line 49, in <module>
    disk.write(data)
    IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Reading and seeking work as they should, and the data read is correct.

**What I know so far**:

1. Handling the drive should be done in sector sized reads/writes/seeks.
2. The disk must be opened with 'rb+' mode.
3. Using both \\.\L: and \\.\PhysicalDriveN produce the same results.
4. The script must run under administrator privileges.
5. Unmounting the drive and trying to access the \\.\PhysicalDriveN file - "Permission Denied" even when running as admin.

To reproduce the error: (WARNING: THIS CODE CAN CORRUPT PHYSICAL DRIVES, RUN ONLY IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING)

```
SOME_OFFSET = 123123
SOME_SIZE = 100
# replace L with the drive letter
disk = open('\\\\.\\L:','r+b')
# or use: (replace N with the drive number)
# disk = open('\\\\.\\PhysicalDriveN','r+b')
disk.seek(SOME_OFFSET*512)
data = disk.read(SOME_SIZE*512)
#modify data...
disk.seek(SOME_OFFSET*512)
disk.write(data)
```

I can't figure out if this is a permission issue or a problem with how I opened the drive.

Comment: The underlying `WriteFile` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Writing directly to a mounted volume isn't allowed. You'll have to dig into this more to lock and dismount the volume before writing to it or the physical drive.

Comment: @eryksun Could you please point me towards the information I need to do so? Thanks!

Comment: You'll be calling [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216) on a volume handle opened with [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858). Here are the [volume control codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365729) to lock, dismount, and unlock the volume. In Python you can use ctypes or PyWin32's [`win32file`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32file.html) module.

Comment: Did you get a working solution?

Comment: @eryksun Unfortunately, I do not have the time to make this work on Windows. In order to make it work in the time I have, I have moved to Linux, where this works seamlessly with opening `/dev/sd*`. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It turns out in most cases all that's required is to lock the volume. I'll add an answer with a context manager that does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the MSDN technical note ["Blocking Direct Write Operations to Volumes and Disks"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118072606/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551353(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Write operations on a DASD volume handle will succeed if the file 
>   system is not mounted, or if:
>
> - The sectors being written to are the boot sectors.
> - The sectors being written to reside outside file system space.
> - The file system has been locked implicitly by requesting 
>     exclusive write access.
> - The file system has been locked explicitly by sending down a 
>     lock/dismount request.
>
> ....
>
> Write operations on a disk handle will succeed if:
>
> - The sectors being written to do not fall within a file system.
> - The sectors being written to fall within a mounted file system 
>     that is locked explicitly.
> - The sectors being written to fall within a file system that is 
>     not mounted or the volume has no file system.

Here's a simple context manager to lock a volume. It uses the [`win32file`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32file.html) and `winoctlcon` modules from PyWin32.

```
import msvcrt
import win32file
import winioctlcon
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def lock_volume(vol):
    hVol = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(vol.fileno())
    win32file.DeviceIoControl(hVol, winioctlcon.FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
                              None, None)
    try:
        yield vol
    finally:
        try:
            vol.flush()
        finally:
            win32file.DeviceIoControl(hVol, winioctlcon.FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME,
                                      None, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VOLUME_PATH = r'\\.\E:'
    OFFSET = 123123
    SIZE = 100

    with open(VOLUME_PATH, 'r+b') as disk:
        with lock_volume(disk):
            disk.seek(OFFSET * 512)
            data = disk.read(SIZE * 512)
            disk.seek(OFFSET * 512)
            disk.write(data)
            input('press enter to unlock the volume')
```