# Writing raw bytes to disk with python and windows

Tags: python-2.7, disk

I Followed this thread:
[Writing raw data to physical disk (flash drive) fails with "Bad file descriptor" on windows - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239626/writing-raw-data-to-physical-disk-flash-drive-fails-with-bad-file-descriptor/40496918#40496918)
and tried to implement eriksun solution on Windows. I can read the disk succesfully, and with the right data (there's only one disk, and I'm opening it with

```
with open("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 'r+b') as disk:
```

However, when I try to write to it, after pressing enter to unlock it I get the error

```
press enter to unlock the volume
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mbrwriter.py", line 113, in <module>
    input('press enter to unlock the volume')
  File "C:\python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "mbrwriter.py", line 91, in lock_volume
    vol.flush()
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What could be the issue?