# Python 3+ How to edit a line in a text file

Tags: python, text-files, line

This has been asked, and it has been answered. Though, the answers do not favor my situation or what I'm trying to achieve.

I have 100's of text files I need to update. I need to update the same one line in each file. I want to open up a text file and only modify a single line. I do not want to re-write the text file using write() or writelines(). I also do not want to use fileinput.input() because that too is re-writing the text file using print statements.

The files contain thousands of lines of critical data and I cannot trust that Python will recreate everything correctly in the files (I understand this will probably never happen). There are several lines that pertain to footer data which is non-critical and that's what I am updating.

How can one update a single line in a text file, without recreating the file. Appending one line in a text must be possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the line be identically the same length before and after?

Comment: Rewriting the file is safer than attempting to modify it in place. You can also verify the critical data is identical in both files.

Comment: Characters in a file are bytes that have a definite position. If you insert content to the middle of the file, you must either write overwrite existing content or shift every following byte to a new position. I don't understand your statement `I cannot trust that Python will recreate everything correctly` -- Of course you can. I don't know why this would be a concern.

Comment: Building off of the comment by @sytech - this is why I asked `Will the line be identically the same length before and after?`.  Unless you are doing a byte-for-byte replacement of your text, it is not possible to actually update in-place as you imagine it. Any tool that claims let you insert a line in-place is actually rewriting the file in some fashion.

Comment: – sytech,

no I can't trust python will recreate everything which is why I said that... The text file data is crucial and one bit can't change. Have you verified yourself that python will recreate everything perfectly in text files flawlessly every single time?

In my industry, everything we use to create data, code, difference files, and etc. must be verified and validated to perform as intended.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you edit the files currently? Also, if you cannot trust python to recreate the whole file, why trust it to edit a few bytes? It sounds like you should be writing in C or something else similarly low-level so that you can have *complete* control of the I/O.

Comment: Maybe I been saying it wrong to try and make it more simple without explaining the entire situation. You have to take my word for it though, I work in an industry where things we use to create output need validated and verified if working with something critical. The parts of the file I want to edit are non-critical and if Python were to mess up, this is highly unlikey i know, then it wouldn't matter. Recreating the entire file though is a different story. There is critical content in there. I explained this above in the OP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in any programming language at the file level. Files simply don't work that way -- especially text-based files which you are likely replacing with different-length data in the middle. You would need raw disk level access (making this a stupidly difficult problem).

If you really want to pursue it, check the raw disk question here:

[Is it possible to get writing access to raw devices using python with windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135398/is-it-possible-to-get-writing-access-to-raw-devices-using-python-with-windows)

EVEN THEN: I'm pretty sure at some level AT LEAST an entire block of data will be read from the drive and re-written (this is physically how drives work if I recall).