# How To Write a python script to recover files from a formatted drive?

Tags: python, file-recovery

I want to write a python script using which I can recover files from a formatted drive. I know formatting doesn't delete the data on drive but marks that space available to overwrite. So how can I recover those files that have not been overwritten ?

Comment: You're probably better off using an existing solution for file recovery, e.g. [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) - this is easy to get wrong, and if you do get it wrong, you can say goodbye to your files forever.

Comment: Although this is a good, answerable question, I think it's a bit broad. At the very least you should narrow down your OS and filesystem you're using. It's also not clear if you need help finding resources about the file recovery procedure or **implementing** a specific procedure (in which case you should describe it, and resources you've found).

Comment: I am using windows and file system NTFS. I need resources about how to write such a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that such a script would work since the python functions and C library implementing file handling are meant to work on an intact File System. What you need to do to recover data is **raw read from the disk** itself. So perhaps your question should be about that.

Related python questions on stackoverflow:

- [Is it possible to get writing access to raw devices using python with windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7135398/1431750)
- [How to open disks in windows and read data at low level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6522644/1431750)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question is not regarding python scripting but file recovery. If that is the case, the strategy you need is different depending on the format of the drive and the operating system you are using.

You can try recovering files without using python at all, it is using specific characteristics of the filesystem and the operating system that you may recover deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using sleuthkit:-

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import re
import os

TYPECODES = ['\-', 'r', 'd', 'b', 'l', 'p', 's', 'w', 'v']
DESCRIPTIONS = [
    'unknown type',
    'regular file',
    'deleted file',
    'block device',
    'symbolic link',
    'named FIFO',
    'shadow file',
    'whiteout file',
    'TSK virtual file',
]
TYPEDICT = dict(zip((tt.strip('\\') for tt in TYPECODES),  DESCRIPTIONS))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Recover files from a disk image using SleuthKit',
)
parser.add_argument(
    'image', type=str, nargs=1, help='path to disk image or mount point',
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-o', '--output', type=str, nargs='?', dest='output', default='recovered',
    help=('output extracted files to this directory [default=./recovered/]'),
)
parser.add_argument(
     '-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose', action='store_true',
    default=False, help=('print progress message'),
)


def recover(imgpath, outpath, verbose=False):

    # check that we can open image
    try:
        with open(imgpath, 'r'):
            pass
    except IOError:
        print('Unable to open %s. Check that the path is '
              'correct, and that you have read permission.' % imgpath)
        return

    # if the output directory exists, check that it's writeable
    if os.path.isdir(outpath):
        if not os.access(outpath, os.W_OK):
            print('Output directory %s is not writeable - check permissions'
                  % outpath)
            return
    # otherwise create it
    else:
        try:
            os.makedirs(outpath)
        except IOError:
            print('Could not create output directory %s - check permissions'
                  % outpath)
            return

    cmd = ['fls', '-i', 'raw', '-p', '-r', imgpath]

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()

    if p.returncode:
        print('Command "%s" failed:\n%s' % (' '.join(cmd), err))
        return

    ft = ''.join(TYPECODES)
    regex = '([%s])/([%s])\s+\*\s+(\d+):\s+(.*)' % (ft, ft)
    success = {}
    failure = {}
    skipped = {}

    for ftype, mtype, inode, relpath in re.findall(regex, out):

        recpath = os.path.join(outpath, relpath)
        recdir, recname = os.path.split(recpath)
        item = {relpath:[imgpath, relpath]}

        # don't try to recover directories
        if os.path.isdir(recpath):
            continue

        # only worth recovering deleted files
        elif (ftype in ('r', 'd')) and (mtype in ('r', 'd')):
            if not os.path.isdir(recdir):
                if os.path.exists(recdir):
                    os.remove(recdir)
                os.makedirs(recdir)
            cmd = ['icat', '-i', 'raw', '-r', imgpath, inode]
            with open(recpath, 'wb', 4096) as outfile:
                err = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=outfile, bufsize=4096)
            if err:
                msg = '[FAILED]'
                failure.update(item)
            else:
                msg = '[RECOVERED]'
                success.update(item)
            if verbose:
                if ftype != mtype:
                    realloc_msg = (
                        '[WARNING: file name structure (%s) '
                        'does not match metadata (%s)]'
                        % (TYPEDICT[ftype], TYPEDICT[mtype]))
                else:
                    realloc_msg = ''
                print('%s %s:%s --> %s %s'
                       % (msg, imgpath, inode, recpath, realloc_msg))
        else:
            # skip unknown/other file types
            if verbose:
                print('[SKIPPED] %s:%s [%s / %s]'
                       % (imgpath, inode, TYPEDICT[ftype], TYPEDICT[mtype]))
            skipped.update(item)

    print('-' * 50)
    nsuccesses = len(success)
    nfailures = len(failure)
    nskipped = len(skipped)
    print('%i files successfully recovered to %s'
          % (len(success), outpath))
    print('%i files skipped' % nskipped)
    print('%i files could not be successfully recovered' % nfailures)
    if nfailures:
        print('\n'.join([(' * ' + pth) for pth in failure.keys()]))
    print('-' * 50)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    imgpath = args.image[0]
    outpath = args.output
    recover(imgpath, outpath, verbose=args.verbose)
```

Just Copy-Paste the Script in your Pycharm.