# Python - Windows Raw Disk unable to read final sectors

Tags: python, windows, winapi, cd-rom, iso9660

When accessing a Raw Disk on Windows via Python `open()`, it for whatever reason does not allow me to read the last 10240 bytes (aka last 5 sectors at 2048 bytes/sector).

When dumping the disc image by other means and comparing the images I can see that the data cannot be assumed to be empty either. In fact, the first of the missing sectors has a UDF Anchor Tag present with related metadata in it. The following sectors are entirely blank.

This is how I dumped the disc contents:

```py
out = open("test.iso", "wb")
with open(r"\\.\D:", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(512)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        out.write(data)
```

If I take that same open() object and tell it to seek to the very end of the disc, it does. So it can clearly reach the sectors at least in terms of seeking. If I then seek back 10240 bytes then attempt to `f.read(...)`, it returns `b''` (empty result) and not an error. It doesn't matter what size I tell it to read either. I tried all kinds of sizes, no-arg/default, 1, 12, 255, 512, 2048, 999999, etc.

Another StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41747833) on a different (but related) question also reported similar findings on Enhanced Audio Discs but seemingly no discussion was brought up since.

I have tested this on multiple DVD discs from varying kinds of studios and creators, all of which are in great condition with it still occurring.

> Example reproducing code:

- I don't know if its gonna happen to you on your system config/disc/reader).
- PyPI Dependencies: wmic
- WMIC reports the disc size-10240 as well, perhaps it's a Windows issue?

```py
import os
from wmi import WMI


DISC_LETTER = "D:"

c = WMI()
disc_info = next(iter(c.Win32_CDROMDrive(Drive=DISC_LETTER)), None)
if not disc_info:
    raise("Disc %s not found...", DISC_LETTER)

disc_size = int(disc_info.size)
disc_size += 10240  # WMIC also reports the size without 10240, but it is real!

f = open(r"\\.\%s" % DISC_LETTER, "rb")
f.seek(disc_size)
if f.tell() == disc_size:
    print("Seeked to the end of the disc...")
f.seek(-10240, os.SEEK_CUR)
if f.tell() == disc_size - (2048 * 5):
    print("Seeked 5 sectors before the end of the disc...")
data = f.read(2048 * 5):
print("Data read (len: %d): %b" % (len(data), data))
```

Any ideas on why this might be would great as I have tried everywhere I could.

Comment: Have you tried manually `seek`ing to the offset of each sector before you read it? Shot in the dark, but...

Comment: I have as explained above, I didn't just attempt -10240, I also tried in increments of 2048 and 512 starting from the last seek loc that worked. (so -10240 relative to the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this occurs as `open(r'\\.\N:')` opens the device with restricted boundaries.

My solution was to open the disc with IOCTL instead of open(). Specifically with [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea), [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol), and [FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_allow_extended_dasd_io).

```py
handle = win32file.CreateFile(
    r"\\.\D:",
    win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    None,
    win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    None
)
if handle == win32file.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to obtain device handle...")
win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle, winioctlcon.FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO, None, None)
```

From here I can use [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) and [SetFilePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) as replacements for read and seek respectively.

I even worked on a new class that loads it all and allows you to dynamically read and seek without having to worry about sector alignment.

```py
class Win32Device:
    """
    Class to read and seek a Windows Raw Device IO object without bother.
    It deals with getting the full size, allowing full access to all sectors,
    and alignment with the discs sector size.
    
    Author: PHOENiX <pragma.exe@gmail.com>
    License: Free, enjoy! This should be a thing open() does by default.
    """

    def __init__(self, target):
        # type: (str) -> None
        self.target = target
        self.sector_size = None
        self.disc_size = None
        self.position = 0

        self.handle = self.get_handle()
        self.geometry = self.get_geometry()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_, **__):
        self.dispose()

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.geometry[-2]

    def dispose(self):
        if self.handle != win32file.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
            win32file.CloseHandle(self.handle)

    def get_target(self):
        # type: () -> str
        """Get UNC target name. Can be `E:` or `PhysicalDriveN`."""
        target = self.target
        if not target.startswith("\\\\.\\"):
            target += rf"\\.\{target}"
        return target

    def get_handle(self):
        # type: () -> int
        """Get a direct handle to the raw UNC target, and unlock its IO capabilities."""
        handle = win32file.CreateFile(
            # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea
            self.get_target(),  # target
            win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,  # desired access
            win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  # share mode, write needed
            None,  # security attributes
            win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,  # creation disposition
            win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  # flags and attributes
            None  # template file
        )
        if handle == win32file.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
            raise RuntimeError("Failed to obtain device handle...")
        # elevate accessible sectors, without this the last 5 sectors (in my case) will not be readable
        win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle, winioctlcon.FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO, None, None)
        return handle

    def get_geometry(self):
        # type: () -> tuple[int, ...]
        """
        Retrieves information about the physical disk's geometry.
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-disk_geometry_ex

        Returns a tuple of:
            Cylinders-Lo
            Cylinders-Hi
            Media Type
            Tracks Per Cylinder
            Sectors Per Track
            Bytes Per Sector
            Disk Size
            Extra Data
        """
        return struct.unpack("8L", win32file.DeviceIoControl(
            self.handle,  # handle
            winioctlcon.IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX,  # ioctl api
            b"",  # in buffer
            32  # out buffer
        ))

    def tell(self):
        # type: () -> int
        """Get current (spoofed) position."""
        return self.position

    def _tell(self):
        # type: () -> int
        """Get current real position."""
        if not self.handle:
            self.handle = self.get_handle()
        return win32file.SetFilePointer(self.handle, 0, win32file.FILE_CURRENT)

    def seek(self, offset, whence=os.SEEK_SET):
        # type: (int, int) -> int
        """Seek at any point in the stream, in an aligned way."""
        if whence == os.SEEK_CUR:
            whence = self.tell()
        elif whence == os.SEEK_END:
            whence = len(self)

        to = whence + offset
        closest = self.align(to)  # get as close as we can while being aligned

        if not self.handle:
            self.handle = self.get_handle()

        pos = win32file.SetFilePointer(self.handle, closest, win32file.FILE_BEGIN)
        if pos != closest:
            raise IOError(f"Seek was not precise...")

        self.position = to  # not actually at this location, read will deal with it
        return to

    def read(self, size=-1):
        # type: (int) -> Optional[bytes]
        """Read any amount of bytes in the stream, in an aligned way."""
        if not self.handle:
            self.handle = self.get_handle()

        sector_size = self.geometry[-3]
        offset = abs(self._tell() - self.tell())

        has_data = b''
        while self._tell() < self.tell() + size:
            res, data = win32file.ReadFile(self.handle, sector_size, None)
            if res != 0:
                raise IOError(f"An error occurred: {res} {data}")
            if len(data) < sector_size:
                raise IOError(f"Read {sector_size - len(data)} less bytes than requested...")
            has_data += data
        # seek to the position wanted + size read, which will then be re-aligned
        self.seek(self.tell() + size)

        return has_data[offset:offset + size]

    def align(self, size, to=None):
        # type: (int, Optional[int]) -> int
        """
        Align size to the closest but floor mod `to` value.
        Examples:
            align(513, to=512)
            >>>512
            align(1023, to=512)
            >>>512
            align(1026, to=512)
            >>>1024
            align(12, to=10)
            >>>10
        """
        if not to:
            to = self.geometry[-3]  # logical bytes per sector value
        return math.floor(size / to) * to
```